# Java mail bounced back mail's address

Tags: java

I have to send messages to many clients. But many of them bounce back. I want a list of those email addresses. How can I get that list from my Java application?

Comment: this is overly broad....

Answer (score 5):

Make a special email address bounced@yourdomain.com where you will capture all bounced emails for analysis.

Add the following header to your sent emails:

```
Return-Path: <bounced@yourdomain.com>
```

Now the emails are going to bounce back to that address.

Read emails at that address from your java program from time to time, for example via IMAP (or depending on your server via a notification interface/whatever), and when you see an email address record it in your database

Note that if you are doing a newsletter app, you should not blacklist the email from the first time, but make count it's bounces, and blacklist it after 3-4 bounces (some people set their email to bounce when they go in vacation and such, so they need special taking care of).

Comment: thanks clyfe. but i want my application to automatically do that.

Comment: What does "automatically" even mean ? That's how it's done, and you have to do it!

Comment: thanks a lot clyfe, i have done it ! thank you very much for your help. its working perfectly. but i still have some problems- when i run my application , it reads all the bounced mails -new and old, read and unread. i want my application to read only the new messages. could u please help me to do it?

Comment: You may delete them from the mailbox once they are added in the database, or use the read/unread marker but in this case make sure no one opens manually the mailbox and tampers emails state. You can read the emails from your app via SMTP protocol. Here's some sample code I already have (PHP sorry) http://stackoverflow.com/a/8468064/283608

Comment: hi clyfe, i have done it . thanks ...thanks a lot for your help. u have been so much help full. thanks...

Answer (score 2):

I solve this question using

```
SMTPMessage msg = new SMTPMessage(getSession()); 
msg.setEnvelopeFrom(bounceAddr);
```

Please see the javamail doc and see it:

```
void com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPMessage.setEnvelopeFrom(String from)
```

Set the From address to appear in the SMTP envelope. Note that this is different than the From address that appears in the message itself. The envelope From address is typically used when reporting errors. See RFC 821 for details.

If set, overrides the `mail.smtp.from` property.

Parameters:
    from the envelope From address